# Check if the Type of an Object is inherited from a specific Class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, types

In C++, how can I check if the type of an object is inherited from a specific class?

```
class Form { };
class Moveable : public Form { };
class Animatable : public Form { };

class Character : public Moveable, public Animatable { };
Character John;

if(John is moveable)
// ...
```

In my implementation the `if` query is executed over all elements of a `Form` list. All objects which type is inherited from `Moveable` can move and need processing for that which other objects don't need.

Comment: Is private inheritance part of the design? It complicates things.

Comment: All inheritances also could be public. That doesn't matter.

Comment: It does matter. With private inheritance it might be tricky to find out.

Comment: That doesn't matter to my program. I am flexible with using either public or private inheritance.

Comment: OK, then public is probably what you want. Private inheritance is basically composition, i.e. a has-a rather than an is-a relationship.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

What you need is `dynamic_cast`. In its pointer form, it will return a null pointer if the cast cannot be performed:

```
if( Moveable* moveable_john = dynamic_cast< Moveable* >( &John ) )
{
    // do something with moveable_john
}
```

Comment: Does this work for private inheritance? It wouldn't make sense if it did.

Comment: What if I have a pointer to `John` instead? Apart from this there is a compiler error saying that `Character` isn't a polymorph type.

Comment: @sharethis: `&John` is a pointer to `John`, if you already have a pointer to `John` you don't need the _address-of operator_ `&`.

Comment: Does this need the **RTTI** allowed? I heard not all compilers have it enabled by default, cause it may be expensive.

Answer (score 16):

You are using private inheritance, so it is not possible to use `dynamic_cast` to determine whether one class is derived from another. However, you can use [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of), which will tell you this at compile time:

```
#include <type_traits>

class Foo {};

class Bar : Foo {};

class Baz {};

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << std::is_base_of<Foo, Bar>::value << '\n'; // true
    std::cout << std::is_base_of<Bar,Foo>::value << '\n';  // false
    std::cout << std::is_base_of<Bar,Baz>::value << '\n';  // false
}
```

Comment: The solution have to work at runtime since I want to iterate over my scene graph which can change anytime.

Comment: @sharethis then it might be important if your inheritance is private. That is why I didn't suggest `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: @sharethis I cannot think of any standard compliant and elegant way that would allow you to do that at runtime.

Answer (score 6):

> Run-time type information (RTTI) is a mechanism that allows the type
>   of an object to be determined during program execution. RTTI was added
>   to the C++ language because many vendors of class libraries were
>   implementing this functionality themselves.

Example:

```
//moveable will be non-NULL only if dyanmic_cast succeeds
Moveable* moveable = dynamic_cast<Moveable*>(&John); 
if(moveable) //Type of the object is Moveable
{
}
```