# Programming a String Based Event Manager in C++

Tags: c++, string, function, events, event-handling

I am working on an event manager where events are represented by a key out of a string and an integer. That means that an event is not represented by a class or object. This way components can communicate through events but stay independent. It is an important guideline for the event manager that events don't need to be registered but everyone can just listen to them or fire them.

(The integer part of the event key is for grouping phases of contentual the same event. E.g. a grenade triggers the events for throwing, flying, landing, exploding. They should be represented as "Grenade" 0, "Grenade" 1, ... "Grenade" 4.)

Optionally events can contain a void pointer to send data referring the event. That could be the velocity of a crash, the id of the killed player.

Every component contains a pointer to the event namager named `Event`. I want to let them register methods or delegates to events.

```
// ideally registering for an event would look like that
Event.Listen("eventname", 0, this->Method);
Event.Listen("eventname", 0, [](){ ... });

// receiving data is optional
Event.Listen("eventname", 0, [](void* Data){ ... });
```

Firing events would ideally work similar.

```
Event.Fire("eventname", 0);
Event.Fire("eventname", 0, Data);

// fires events "eventname" 0, "eventname" 1, ... "eventname" 5
Event.FireRange("eventname", 0, 5);
```

The event manager holds a list of the events. That means the event key and a vector of all registered functions.

```
typedef unordered_map<pair<string, int>, vector<function>> ListEvent;
ListEvent List;
```

The vector stores all functions registered to a specific event. I tried using function pointers, member function pointers and `std::function`s. But nothing worked the way I wanted. Here are some of my questions related to this event manager: [Check if two std::function are Equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989743/check-if-two-stdfunction-are-equal), [Store Function Pointers to any Member Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988320/store-function-pointers-to-any-member-function), [Check if the Type of an Object is inherited from a specific Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963294/check-if-the-type-of-an-object-is-inherited-from-a-specific-class).

It is important for a listening function to have access to the member of it's class. And I would like to register lambda functions in one line of code.

**Do you have any idea or technique to approach coding such an event manager?**

I tried to present my problem in a general manner but if you need additional explanation or code please feel free to comment.

Comment: "I want to let them register methods". 
Pointer to a method of some object of some class is a pair of pointers: instance_ptr and function_ptr (the method per se). If you allow your Event to hold references to such pairs then what should happen with events created for objects that were deleted after someone subscribed for their events? I believe understanding of this problem is somehow critical for you to do a right design.

Comment: @c-smile: I agree, too many questions, too little thinking. Time to step back and let it rest for a while.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Store Function Pointers to any Member Function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988320/store-function-pointers-to-any-member-function)

Comment: @c-smile: By the concept, all event firing and listening components stay alive all the time the game is running. Of course an approach taking care of deleted objects would be appreciable but it isn't essentially needed.

Comment: @sharethis if objects are alive then

void my_object::firstCry() { 
   evt0.subscribe([&](int p) { this->got_signal(p); } 
}

void my_object::got_signal(int param) {...}

would work for you. See my answer below.

Comment: I am a type freak, and honestly this idea of using strings and integers to represent anything and everything does not appeal to me so much. You might feel that things are decoupled, since you don't need to share includes, but you are wrong in this. They are coupled because ("grenade", 5) has a specific meaning for both the sender and the receiver => by using generic types you are just shoving the coupling under the carpet: it's hidden, but it's there... [to be continued]

Comment: [continuing] ...  I recommend you document yourself on 2 Design Pattern: **Observer** deals with the idea of Publish/Subscribe, so it's the heart of your design; **Visitor** deals with the idea of decoupling and dispatching virtually or in other words passing the right type to the right handler. With a correct *Visitor* implementation you could get typed events (`Grenade`) with a typed payload. Because a `Visitor` involves tight coupling, you might want to read on *Acyclic Visitor*; it might also turn out that *one manager per event type* helps keeping things tidy. Time for **templates** ?

Comment: I will read about these two pattern **Observer** and **Visitor**. Of course all components are coupled contentual. But I thing they will ever be. Decided for a string key to don't need global definition of all possible messages or one manager per event type. This will be much more productive and flexible, I think. However I will study both mentioned pattern and decide then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is quick working sketch:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::function<void(int param)> callback;

struct Event {
  std::vector<callback> subs;//criptions  

  void subscribe(callback cb) { subs.push_back(cb); }
  void fire(int param = 0) { for(callback& cb : subs) cb(param); }
};

void some_free_func(int param) { std::cout << "some_free_func got signal" << std::endl; }

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Event evt0; 
  evt0.subscribe(some_free_func);

  evt0.subscribe([](int p) { std::cout << "some_lambda got signal" << std::endl; } );

  evt0.fire();
    return 0;
}
```

Conceptually it roughly does what you need but you should think of ownership policy here. Check my question above.

EDIT: if you say that ownership is not an issue then this may work:

```
void my_object::firstCry() { 
   evt0.subscribe([=](int p) { this->got_signal(p); }); // inst/method thunk 
}

void my_object::got_signal(int param) {...}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am afraid that this won't do. If you read the 3 previous questions, you'll realize that the OP is running in circle and making no progress, at all, between one question and the next. There have already been answers suggesting `std::function` or other mechanisms. Honestly, I think this one should get closed, and probably one or two of those he already asked. It's more spamming than anything else at this rate.

Comment: @Matthieu M, If to put aside personal stuff then technically that kind of questions make sense by themselves. Events, signal/slot, etc. will be asked about again and again.

Comment: @Matthieu M. You are right, my programming skill bad. Moreover I wrote most of my code in C# and sometimes it is not so easy for me to think "C++ like". Now I want to write a game, and not primarily the architecture. So after a working event system I can concentrate on other things. Anyway, I learned a lot the last days and I like that. But I can understand that my stuck behavior annoys other users so it would be acceptable for me closing these questions. (By the way your comment isn't related to that answer but to my question.)

Comment: @sharethis: It's not that your programming skill is in question, it's that like everyone else you likely need time to assimilate new ideas and see how they work. And C++ being a difficult language (many gotchas to watch out for) means that you are facing both conceptual *and* technical issues at the same time, it's definitely a challenge!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got my event manager working! Maybe I will still improve it next days but it already does it's job!